# Ionic 4 Firebase Return

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm using a function to check whether the values (value) in the documents within my collection are the same as in a string arrays (this.values), but I'm unable to return the true values for this condition in string format.

```
Function() {

this.afs.collection('nameCollection', ref => ref.where( 'value', "in" , this.values

)).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {

if(res.length > 0

{

console.log(res.toString()) // <--------------------------

}

});

}
```

Result

```
console.log : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What should I do to return the values in string format?

Answer (score 1):

did you try JSON.stringfy(res); ?